# How to make an sbt project reference external java sources

Tags: scala, sbt

Could anyone post a code example of how to reference an external java source directory in an sbt project?

If I do the following

```
override def mainSourceRoots = super.mainSourceRoots +++ externalsourcepath
```

the sbt compile task will properly find and compile the java sources but then fail. e.g.

```
[info] Compilation successful.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Path /full/path/to/java/class/com/foo/bar/SomeClass.java not in .
```

Comment: Would it be easier to just symlink the external source path to /your/project/src/main/java ?

Comment: Yes you're right, and I did do that as a last resort. It does work, but I've actually got a slightly more complicated situation, with a number of "feeder" subprojects - I can copy them all, or even script it, but it seems a bit silly to have to write scripts to work around a build tool - I'd certainly like to be able to do it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBT 0.9 will support external sub-projects. Until then, I would suggest to build the other one to a JAR, and drop the results into `./lib`.

Comment: Ahhh. At least it's a relief to know the reason I couldn't get it to work. Thank you.

Comment: On a side note, have you come across this as an actually documented issue in sbt, or is it something you've come across through useage?

Answer (score 0):

If the Java projects use Maven or Ivy you can probably install them locally and declare them as dependencies in the SBT project. If you need something like Maven's reactor where you can mix Java and Scala submodules within the same super project, and compile them in order at the same time, you can try [SBT Subprojects](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/SubProjects)